# How to add labels to mapview

Tags: r, leaflet, mapview

This may be an easy question but for some reason can't figure out how to add labels to each region or polygon in my real map. How can I add the NAME_ASCI names to this map?

```
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)

class(franconia)
  head(franconia)           
 mapview(franconia, alpha.regions = 0.2, aplha = 1)  #Whats the option in mapview to add labels?
```

Comment: `mapview(franconia, alpha.regions = 0.2, aplha = 1, label = "NAME_ASCI")`

Comment: I am not able to see the label on the regions. @TimSalabim How can I make the label bigger and red color?

Comment: This code prints labels but no the map of franconia `mapview(franconia)  %>% addStaticLabels(., label = franconia$NAME_ASCI)` I wonder why.